# jQuery slideDown and slideUp toggle issues

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup, navbar

So basically I'm just starting out with jQuery and JS and I have hit a problem.

I have a small menu that when the user clicks one of the links, the content slides down. If there is already a box open, it slides up.

My problem is, when you click on the same link to close it again, it slides-up, but then because jQuery code tells it to slide down again, it does. This means that you can never close one the bits of content once one of them are open.

My jQuery Code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 

    jQuery(".radius5").hide();

    jQuery("a#contact-btn").click(function() {
        jQuery(".radius5").slideUp();
        jQuery("div#contact").slideDown("slow");
    });

    jQuery("a#about-btn").click(function() {
        jQuery(".radius5").slideUp();
        jQuery("div#about").slideDown("slow"); 
    });

    jQuery("a#portfolio-btn").click(function() {
        jQuery(".radius5").slideUp();
        jQuery("div#portfolio").slideDown("slow-up");
    });

});
```

and HTML code (simplified of course):

```
    <a id="contact-btn" class="btn-slide" href="#">Contact</a>
    <a id="about-btn" class="btn-slide" href="#">About</a>
    <a id="portfolio-btn" class="btn-slide" href="#">Portfolio</a>

   <div id="contact" class="radius5">Contact Us</div>
   <div id="about" class="radius5">About Us</div>
   <div id="portfolio" class="radius5">Our Portfolio</div>
```

I also have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ePRsz/1/) link.

I'm sure it's really easy to answer. I've tried using `addClass` and `removeClass` but couldn't seem to get it quite right. Can anyone help?

Regards,

Tom Oakley

Answer (score 0):

I would tweak your HTML slightly to keep track of which elements should show/hide using the `href` property (per @powerbuoy's comment):

```
<a id="contact-btn" class="btn-slide" href="#contact">Contact</a>
<a id="about-btn" class="btn-slide" href="#about">About</a>
<a id="portfolio-btn" class="btn-slide" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>

<div id="contact" class="radius5">Contact Us</div>
<div id="about" class="radius5">About Us</div>
<div id="portfolio" class="radius5">Our Portfolio</div>
```

Then your JavaScript becomes a lot simpler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".radius5").hide();

    $("a.btn-slide").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $menu = $($(this).attr("href"));

        $(".radius5").slideUp();

        if ($menu.is(":hidden")) {
            $menu.slideDown("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/zLqYn/

You could also take a look at [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle), but I noticed that you're using different durations depending on whether you're sliding up or down. If the durations are both the same (e.g. you slide up and down with a duration of `"slow"`), you could make the code even shorter by using `slideToggle`.

Comment: Use the `href` attribute instead of your own `data-menu`. Then it makes sense without JS as well.

Comment: @powerbuoy: Yep, you're right that's an excellent idea. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove the current element from the `$(".radius5")` selection so it doesn't get slid up. You can also make your code more compact by handling all the `click` events in one event handler:

```
$(function(){

    //cache the `.radius5` selector so it doesn't have to be re-calculated in the event handler
    var $radius5 = $(".radius5").hide();

    //bind a `click` event handler to all three of your buttons, notice to select multiple items we just put a comma in between the selectors
    $("#contact-btn, #about-btn, #portfolio-btn").click(function() {

        //get the ID of the element to slideDown
        var slide_down = "#" + this.id.replace('-btn', '');

        //slideUp all but the current element
        $radius5.not(slide_down).slideUp();

        //slideDown the current element
        $(slide_down).slideDown("slow");
    });                 
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ePRsz/5/

**UPDATE**

I just re-read your question and if you want the currently slid-down element to slide-up if its nav link is clicked again you can change `.slideDown()` for `.slideToggle()`:

```
$(function(){

    var $radius5 = $(".radius5").hide();

    $("#contact-btn, #about-btn, #portfolio-btn").click(function() {
        var slide_down = "#" + this.id.replace('-btn', '');
        $radius5.not(slide_down).slideUp();
        $(slide_down).slideToggle("slow");
    });                  
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ePRsz/13/